# How can inherited functions with the same name get treated as overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope, overloading

I create a function in class A and class A is a base class sub-object of B class. In class B I create a function with the same name and signature with one in class A. In the function in class B, I want to call the function in class A but it not get overloaded. How can I use it ?

```
class Document{
public:
void Input(){};
};

class Book:public Document{
public:
void Input(){this->Input();} //I want to use Document's function here
};
```

Comment: You need `virtual` keyword to allow polymorphism, your currect code has a function which hides another.

Comment: Note that there is no overloading here, and no possibility of overloading. Overloaded functions have the same name and **different argument lists**; when the function is called, the compiler looks at the arguments to figure out which overload to call. Here, both versions of `Input()` take no arguments, so they cannot be overloaded. You've gotten a good answer to your question; my comment here is just about terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly refer to it with the base class name:

```
void Input(){Document::Input();}
```